# Docking Station for 13" MacBook Pro and Surface Pro 3

Tags: hardware, hardware-recommendation

Is there a docking station that is compatible with both 13" Macbook Pro (2015 model A1502) and a Surface Pro 3?

I am looking for one that has

1. Connectivity up to two monitors (DVI/HDMI/VGA)
2. Ethernet adapter
3. 1 USB Port
4. Portable

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a client that has used this model docking station and he seems to really like it.  It's the [Pluggable USB Docking Station](http://amzn.to/22LwTzS).

**Update:**  The USB docking stations in general seem to have an issue with the DisplayLink technology meaning that the dock with the exception of the display will work just fine.

From [DisplayLink's website](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/528023):

> Known issues with DisplayLink on OS X 10.9, 10.10 and 10.11
>   (Mavericks, Yosemite and El Capitan)
>
> The
>   following minor issues have been found on OS X 10.9, 10.10 and 10.11
>   and do not currently have a resolution:
>
> - Corruption around window borders for Carbon applications (for example Microsoft Office 2011)
> - Afew applications can show corruption and/or missing contents while
>     updating windows contents. Examples are Maps, iBooks and the Dock.
> - The window server can crash logging our the user when minimising
>     applications, for example iTunes.
> - Apple menu icon misplaced on DisplayLink screens
> - Since 10.11 El Capitan, corruption shown while mirroring DisplayLink screens
>
> The following issues have been found on OS X 10.9, 10.10 and have been resolved in 10.11: 
>   - The Window Server crashes logging out the user during some full screen transitions, for example Show Desktop and Mission Control.
>
> These issues are beingworked on jointly between DisplayLink and Apple.

This is an ongoing issue.  If you can live with video issues, then pretty much any USB 3.0 dock will work.  If video is super important, then you are going to need separate docks.